# I get a white screen when sharing Minecraft classic links from Minecraft.net

Tags: minecraft-classic-browser

If I go directly to classic.minecraft.net, I can get the app to work on my browser. If I try running one of the links it gave me, I get a white screen and no error in the browser console. So I cannot use the invite to play with friends. Any advice when trying to play together on the website ?

Comment: At this point, it's hard to say. You'd likely have to do some back-door work in order to identify what the issue is, and potentially hard-code in the connection. That said, that's just an idea of what might be possible, off the top of my head. –

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that this is no longer supported. This [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/bm90ft/minecraft_classic_multiplayer_not_working_help/) describes the same issue, and is over 2 years old. The *only* solution provided is to refresh the page:

> I got it working with some of my friends you refresh the page a bunch then wait for it to load
>
> *its worth noting that it takes a while to load

However, [this forum](https://f.classicube.net/topic/100-minecraft-classic-multiplayer-links-classicminecraftnet/) from May 2020 states that the multiplayer functionality was removed entirely.

> Yes I confirm the multiplayer mode has been deleted and in addition it has big slowdown

If you want, you can still try to use the reddit suggestion of refreshing until it loads, but it's likely that won't work.

---

<sup>I have also tested this myself, on the same PC, on a different PC on the same network, as well as a PC outside the network, all with the same result</sup>

Comment: Ben thank you. Is there a way to prevent classic minecraft from starting up with the links generating page, if the function was removed ? Maybe a different ? query string?

Comment: At this point, it's hard to say. You'd likely have to do some back-door work in order to identify what the issue is, and potentially hard-code in the connection. That said, that's just an idea of what *might* be possible, off the top of my head.

Comment: I'm up for modifying the code if there is a github for it! Is the code available ?